# How to authenticate React Native user by React Web page?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, authentication, single-sign-on

In our company we decided that we will not use separate Login/Register/ChangePassword forms for `React Web`and `React Native` and we will rather make `React Web` forms once and them reuse them in React Native.

This means that user of Native app clicks on `Login` button and default browser is opened to log in. After successfull login, user is redirected back into Native app as alrady logged.

I think this is very common in Hybrid Native apps, but I not found any docs how to achieve this in React Native.

Can anybody help me with quick example or redirect me to some docs/post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [react-native-webview](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview) to open the company login url, and pass a injectedJavascript props to WebView component that when the user is logged in you get the elements with user's data(Ex: getElementById("userName")) and close WebView redirecting user back to the app.

[Extra Information here](https://medium.com/capriza-engineering/communicating-between-react-native-and-the-webview-ac14b8b8b91a);

[WebView props here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Reference.md) so you can know how to control it.